# Appropriate Model for inflated variable at non zero value

Tags: modeling, censoring, tobit-regression, zero-inflation

I have a question regarding the appropriate regression model for a continuous variable that ranges from zero to 10. This variable has a large concentration of observations in the "10" value (almost 50 percent of my sample). Below is the histogram for my dependent variable.

[image: histogram]

I considered this a case of left-censored regression model and estimated a Tobit model. However, I am now considering that this may be a case of a "10"-inflated model. In this case, how can I estimate the inflated regression model, as my dependent variable is not a count variable, but rather a continuous one?

Comment: You should tell us much more! What is you measuring, experimantal setup, sample size, what is your goal, ...